# How do I properly extend an existing schema for Propel without corrupting version tables?

Tags: schema, versioning, propel, extend

I wanted to add a column (IS_ACTIVE) to an existing table (Book). So I have extended the schema file (schema.xml) accordingly. I went through the following commands as described in the docs.

```
propel-gen om
propel-gen convert-conf
propel-gen sql
```

I've stripped all the unnecessary parts from the schema.sql file such that only the affected table would be dropped and recreated. Then I executed:

```
propel-gen insert-sql
```

Unfortunately the version table has not been updated in the process, yielding insert errors such as this one

```
Unable to execute SELECT statement [SELECT book_version.ID, book_version.TITLE,
 book_version.URL, book_version.COMMENTS, book_version.IS_ACTIVE,
 book_version.VERSION FROM `book_version` WHERE book_version.ID=:p1 ORDER BY 
 book_version.VERSION DESC LIMIT 1] [wrapped: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found:
 1054 Unknown column 'book_version.IS_ACTIVE' in 'field list']
```

when calling

```
$book->save();
```

How do I properly extend an existing schema.xml without running into this?

Comment: Why not just add the `<column>` to your schema.xml and then run `propel-gen sql-diff` and `propel-gen migrate`? [Documentation link](http://propelorm.org/documentation/10-migrations.html)

Comment: That's even better! Thanks, [jakerella](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1985406/jakerella), for the hint.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

first make a buildtime-conf.xml  file as same location on runtime-conf.xml and content have  also  same like runtime-conf.xml.

then run below command  one by one .

1. propel-gen diff
2. propel-gen migrate
3. prople-gen om
4. propel-gen  convert-conf

   i think this will help you .

Thanks.

Comment: Worked like a charm. I've executed 3. and 4. before 1. and 2. but I think that doesn't matter because 3. and 4. affect only the code and 1. and 2. affect only the database.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested, you should cut any SQL statement from the resulting SQL file (schema.sql) referring to tables that should stay as they are. But besides statements referring to the table that should be changed **also statements referring to the respective version tables have to be included in this file**. Then you can run

```
propel-gen insert-sql
```

and this should solve the problem.